# How to embed a Room entity that isn't directly related?

Tags: android, android-room

I have three basic entities that represent the tables in my Room database: **Country**, **State** and **City**.

To embed a list of cities within a state, I've created a POJO, called **StateWithCities**:

```
package org.example.roomtest;

import java.util.List;
import androidx.room.Embedded;
import androidx.room.Relation;

public class StateWithCities {

    @Embedded
    public State state;

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "_id", // This is the `states`.`_id` column.
            entityColumn = "state_id" // This is the `cities`.`state_id` column.
    )
    public List<City> cities;
}
```

which I can then return from a query in my **StateDao** interface:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `states`")
LiveData<List<StateWithCities>> getAllStatesWithCities();
```

However, I would now like to create a query in my ***CountryDao*** interface that can return the ***cities*** associated with a country.

(Countries and cities are related via the `states` table. So, as you'd expect, `cities`.`state_id` relates to `states`.`_id`. And `states`.`country_id` relates to `countries`.`_id`.)

So I have created a **CountryWithStatesWithCities** POJO:

```
package org.example.roomtest;

import java.util.List;
import androidx.room.Embedded;
import androidx.room.Relation;

public class CountryWithStatesWithCities {

    @Embedded
    public Country country;

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "_id", // This is the `country`.`_id` column.
            entityColumn = "country_id" // This is the `states`.`country_id` column.
    )
    public List<StateWithCities> stateWithCities;
}
```

At this point, everything compiles fine. But when I add this query to **CountryDao**:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `countries`")
LiveData<List<CountryWithStatesWithCities>> getAllCountriesWithStatesWithCities();
```

I get these compile errors that refer to my two classes, above:

```
> ...StateWithCities.java:7: error: The class must be either @Entity or @DatabaseView.
> public class StateWithCities {
>        ^
```

and

```
> ...CountryWithStatesWithCities.java:16: error: Cannot find the child entity column `country_id` in org.team_love.shapethefuture.roomtest.StateWithCities. Options: 
>     public List<StateWithCities> stateWithCities;
>                                  ^
```

These errors seem to be telling me that my **CountryDao** interface needs to be referencing *Entities* (or DatabaseViews) rather than POJOs. So, what is the correct approach to solving my requirement: *How to embed a Room entity that isn't directly related?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your entity class explicitly describing `CountryWithStatesWithCities`, since Room has a problem to infer it from the context:

```
public class CountryWithStatesWithCities {

    @Embedded
    public Country country;

    @Relation(
            entity = State.class, <- this should be added explicitly
            parentColumn = "_id", // This is the `country`.`_id` column.
            entityColumn = "country_id" // This is the `states`.`country_id` column.
    )
    public List<StateWithCities> stateWithCities;
}
```